# Erro ao baixar phpDoc

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, documentação

Sistema Operacional: ubuntu 14.04
PHP 5.3.10
curl 7.22.0

Estou tentando baixar o phpdocumentor 2.0.0. Porém dá esse erro:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.2 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.0 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor 2 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v2.0.0]
```

O composer.json:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    }
}
```

Estou utilizando o comando:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Eu devo alterar o .json ?
.

Comment: Instalaste o php5-xsl? `apt-get install php5-xsl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mensagem de erro diz:

> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.

Ou seja, você precisa instalar a extensão xsl do PHP que é necessária.

No Ubuntu, use o comando a seguir:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

Comment: No windows como seria ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva no Windows, provavelmente, seria necessário habilitar a extensão no php.ini (removendo o comentário ";" da linha correspondente).

Comment: great, save me some time, thanks!